# Avoiding ambiguous parameters in templated Eigen functions with MSVS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, compiler-bug

I'm writing some funtions that are supposed to take `Eigen::Array` as an input.
The Arrays are of constant size, but the size is a template parameter and should be deducted from the input.
When compiling with MSVS, i have to supply the size to the function or it will result in an error.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>

template<unsigned short t_iSize>
void foo(const Eigen::Array<unsigned short, t_iSize, 1>&)
{

}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Array<unsigned short, 3, 1> test;
    // foo(test);    // Compiler errors C2672 and C2784
    foo<3>(test);    // Giving the size solves the errors
}
```

The size should be possible to be deducted from the variable `test`, but it seems to fail when computing the template arguments 4 and 5 for the Array.

> Error C2672: "foo": no matching overloaded function found.
>
> Error C2784: "void foo(const Eigen::Array< unsigned short,t_iSize,1,|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:,_Rows,1> &)": could not deduce template argument for "const Eigen::Array< unsigned short,t_iSize,1,|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:,_Rows,1> &" from "Eigen::Array< unsigned short,3,1,0,3,1>".

Is it possible to avoid this problem when taking the Eigen::Array, or do I need to take Eigen::ArrayBase as a function parameter? I would like to avoid that, as it obscures the fact that the function only takes this specific type of arrays.

Edit:

As Jarod42 noted, the template parameter should be of type int.
Visual Studio can compile the code with this mistake.
It fails in deducing the parameter `_Rows`, though, where other compilers can do so.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Qf05OR) you can see the problem I ran into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration of `Eigen::Array` is

```
template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
class Eigen::Array;
```

Your function uses wrong type for row, `unsigned short` should be `int`.

```
template <int t_iSize>
void foo(const Eigen::Array<unsigned short, t_iSize, 1>&)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b6gRCe)

As workaround for your issue with Msvc, you might do:

- apply the default value manually:

  ```
  template <int t_iSize>
  void bar(const Eigen::Array<unsigned short, t_iSize, 1, 0, t_iSize, 1>&) {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- or add the extra template (and so the code is even more generic):

  ```
  template <int t_iSize, int Options, int MaxRows, int MaxCols>
  void foo(const Eigen::Array<unsigned short, t_iSize, 1, Options, MaxRows, MaxCols>&) {
    // ...
  }
  ```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GAhXDs)

Comment: Changing the template parameter from unsigned short to int doesn't make it compileable in my case

Comment: Provided Demo link which show issue with old variant. (cannot reproduce on msvc though, maybe flag?)

Comment: I linked the problem I had in my question. MSVS seems to ignore the mismatched template types, but has a problem when the template parameters depend on each other

Comment: Then possible workaround [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GAhXDs)

Comment: These two workarounds do the job perfectly. Do you want to write a complete answer?

Comment: @DanielBauer: added.